# Universal multiple file uploader for Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I want to create universal multiple file uploader, but I don't know what approach should I choose to develop it.

I have Attachment model and attachments table in the database. Also I have model Item and table items. These two a connected via item_attachment table (maybe it will be morph connection in the future, so many models can have attachments).

I thought about several approaches (examples are for create form for item):

- Use some js uploader (like Dropzone) and develop separate controller
  to handle uploads (AttachmentsController). So when I upload files,
  controller will return json response with id's to js, and then they
  will be inserted to the form as hidden elements. After submitting
  form, they will be attached to the item.
- Don't use js, and process uploads directly in ItemsController.
- Don't use js, develop a Service, where uploads will be handled and
  call it's methods in ItemsController.

What can you recommend? Maybe you have your approach?

Thanks